# How do i link my Java project with a another java project which I've converted to a Library?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, navigation, lib

I've created a Java Splash Screen project and have imported another IntroScreen project via source code and converted it into a Library. Now I need to link these two together and in the following order: Splash Screen --> IntroScreen.

**Splash Screen Java Code**

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;

public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this,IntroActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        },2500);
    }
}
```

**IntroActivity Code from Library (from converted library)**

```
    private ViewPager screenPager;
    IntroViewPagerAdapter introViewPagerAdapter ;
    TabLayout tabIndicator;
    Button btnNext;
    int position = 0 ;
    Button btnGetStarted;
    Animation btnAnim ;
    TextView tvSkip;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // make the activity on full screen

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);


        // when this activity is about to be launch we need to check if its openened before or not

        if (restorePrefData()) {

            Intent mainActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class );
            startActivity(mainActivity);
            finish();


        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_intro);

        // hide the action bar

        getSupportActionBar().hide();

        // ini views
        btnNext = findViewById(R.id.btn_next);
        btnGetStarted = findViewById(R.id.btn_get_started);
        tabIndicator = findViewById(R.id.tab_indicator);
        btnAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.button_animation);
        tvSkip = findViewById(R.id.tv_skip);

        // fill list screen

        final List<ScreenItem> mList = new ArrayList<>();
        mList.add(new ScreenItem("Fresh Food","Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua, consectetur  consectetur adipiscing elit",R.drawable.img1));
        mList.add(new ScreenItem("Fast Delivery","Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua, consectetur  consectetur adipiscing elit",R.drawable.img2));
        mList.add(new ScreenItem("Easy Payment","Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua, consectetur  consectetur adipiscing elit",R.drawable.img3));

        // setup viewpager
        screenPager =findViewById(R.id.screen_viewpager);
        introViewPagerAdapter = new IntroViewPagerAdapter(this,mList);
        screenPager.setAdapter(introViewPagerAdapter);

        // setup tablayout with viewpager

        tabIndicator.setupWithViewPager(screenPager);

        // next button click Listner

        btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                position = screenPager.getCurrentItem();
                if (position < mList.size()) {

                    position++;
                    screenPager.setCurrentItem(position);


                }

                if (position == mList.size()-1) { // when we rech to the last screen

                    // TODO : show the GETSTARTED Button and hide the indicator and the next button

                    loaddLastScreen();


                }



            }
        });

        // tablayout add change listener


        tabIndicator.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.BaseOnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                if (tab.getPosition() == mList.size()-1) {

                    loaddLastScreen();

                }


            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });



        // Get Started button click listener

        btnGetStarted.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                //open main activity

                Intent mainActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(mainActivity);
                // also we need to save a boolean value to storage so next time when the user run the app
                // we could know that he is already checked the intro screen activity
                // i'm going to use shared preferences to that process
                savePrefsData();
                finish();



            }
        });

        // skip button click listener

        tvSkip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                screenPager.setCurrentItem(mList.size());
            }
        });



    }

    private boolean restorePrefData() {


        SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("myPrefs",MODE_PRIVATE);
        Boolean isIntroActivityOpnendBefore = pref.getBoolean("isIntroOpnend",false);
        return  isIntroActivityOpnendBefore;



    }

    private void savePrefsData() {

        SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("myPrefs",MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("isIntroOpnend",true);
        editor.commit();


    }

    // show the GETSTARTED Button and hide the indicator and the next button
    private void loaddLastScreen() {

        btnNext.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        btnGetStarted.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        tvSkip.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        tabIndicator.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        // TODO : ADD an animation the getstarted button
        // setup animation
        btnGetStarted.setAnimation(btnAnim);



    }
}
```

**IntroViewPagerAdapter code (from converted Library)**

```
public class IntroViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

   Context mContext ;
   List<ScreenItem> mListScreen;

    public IntroViewPagerAdapter(Context mContext, List<ScreenItem> mListScreen) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mListScreen = mListScreen;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View layoutScreen = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_screen,null);

        ImageView imgSlide = layoutScreen.findViewById(R.id.intro_img);
        TextView title = layoutScreen.findViewById(R.id.intro_title);
        TextView description = layoutScreen.findViewById(R.id.intro_description);

        title.setText(mListScreen.get(position).getTitle());
        description.setText(mListScreen.get(position).getDescription());
        imgSlide.setImageResource(mListScreen.get(position).getScreenImg());

        container.addView(layoutScreen);

        return layoutScreen;





    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mListScreen.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object o) {
        return view == o;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {

        container.removeView((View)object);

    }
}
```

**ScreenItem Code (from converted Library)**

```
public class ScreenItem {

    String Title,Description;
    int ScreenImg;

    public ScreenItem(String title, String description, int screenImg) {
        Title = title;
        Description = description;
        ScreenImg = screenImg;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        Title = title;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        Description = description;
    }

    public void setScreenImg(int screenImg) {
        ScreenImg = screenImg;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return Title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return Description;
    }

    public int getScreenImg() {
        return ScreenImg;
    }
}
```